# How to revert all changes and go to previous version of the source code? Get-this specific version Vs Roll-back?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I have a need to revert all the changes and go back to a specific version of the source code in Visual Studio TFS. I chose 'get this specific version' and gave the changeset number. But somehow, reverting multiple times using this option did not deploy the changes properly. I also manually deleted all the changes made after that specific changeset but still the app showed up errors that were related to the deleted code changes.

Please let me know how I can go back to a specific version that changes all the files properly. My requirement is to have the source code with all the same files as of that particular version.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? What error did you get when you made changes? Have you tried to compare the versions?

Comment: Does overwrite all files help you?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to compare your local version with the server version after you get the specific version, to see whether there are different files.

And try to select the checkbox below to see whether it helps you. You might get the files not match local version only from specific version, for the same files, the are not overwritten.

[image]